# OpenGL: Keep drawing inside a region on a plane in 3D space

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

Step 1: I use glVertex() to draw a shape, say a rectangle, in 3D space.

Step 2: I then draw things inside this rectangle - for example with glutStrokeCharacter() and with glVertex() again.

I need to keep what are drawn in step 2 inside the rectangle drawn in step 1, clipping away anything that goes outside the boundary. Can someone give some hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Render bounding geometry into [stencil buffer](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing).
2. Enable stencil test
3. Render regular geometry into color buffer; the stencil test will prevent fragments outside the bounding geometry from writing to the color buffer.

Comment: @TomBennett: Edited.

Comment: I am not sure how to set the stencil buffer in my situation. I am operating on a rectangle wireframe drawn with glBegin(GL_LINES); with multiple glVertex() calls. I then want to write text only inside this wireframe and clipping everything outside. The stencil buffers seems to operate at the pixel level and all examples I find have some filling inside. But in my case, with just the lines, I am not sure the stencil buffer can be properly set. If you have some hints, let me know.

Comment: @TomBennett: Disable color writes, enable stencil writes, draw *filled* rectangle with the wireframe vertices to populate stencil buffer.  Enable color writes, enable stencil test, draw wireframe rectangle & text.